# How to configure Databricks token inside Docker File

Tags: docker, databricks, databricks-cli

I have a docker file where I want to

1. Download the Databricks CLI
2. Configure the CLI by adding a host and token
3. And then running a python file that hits the Databricks token

I am able to install the CLI in the docker image, and I have a working python file that is able to submit the job to the Databricks API but Im unsure of how to configure my CLI within docker.

Here is what I have

```
FROM python
MAINTAINER nope

# Creating Application Source Code Directory
RUN mkdir -p /src

# Setting Home Directory for containers
WORKDIR /src

# Installing python dependencies
RUN pip install databricks_cli

# Not sure how to do this part???
# databricks token kicks off the config via CLI
RUN databricks configure --token

# Copying src code to Container
COPY . /src

# Start Container
CMD echo $(databricks --version)

#Kicks off Pythern Job
CMD ["python", "get_run.py"]
```

If I was to do `databricks configure --token` in the CLI it would prompt for the configs like this :

```
databricks configure --token
Databricks Host (should begin with https://):
```

Comment: were you able to figure this out? Could you post the solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

It's better not to do it this way for multiple reasons:

1. It's insecure - if you configure Databricks CLI this way it will generate a file inside the container that could be read by anyone who has access to it
2. Token has time-to-live (default is 90 days) - this means that you'll need to rebuild your containers regularly...

Instead it's just better to pass two environment variables to the container, and they will be picked up by the `databricks` command.  These are `DATABRICKS_HOST` and `DATABRICKS_TOKEN` as it described in the [documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/cli/index.html#set-up-authentication).

Answer (score 0):

When `databricks configure` is run successfully, it writes the information to the file `~/.databrickscfg`:

```
[DEFAULT]
host = https://your-databricks-host-url
token = your-api-token
```

One way you could set this in the container is by using a startup command (syntax here for `docker-compose.yml`):

```
/bin/bash -ic "echo '[DEFAULT]\nhost = ${HOST_URL}\ntoken = ${TOKEN}' > ~/.databrickscfg"
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not very secure to put your token in the DockerFile. However, if you want to pursue this approach you can use the code below.

```
RUN export DATABRICKS_HOST=XXXXX && \
    export DATABRICKS_API_TOKEN=XXXXX && \
    export DATABRICKS_ORG_ID=XXXXX && \
    export DATABRICKS_PORT=XXXXX && \
    export DATABRICKS_CLUSTER_ID=XXXXX && \
    echo "{\"host\": \"${DATABRICKS_HOST}\",\"token\": \"${DATABRICKS_API_TOKEN}\",\"cluster_id\":\"${DATABRICKS_CLUSTER_ID}\",\"org_id\": \"${DATABRICKS_ORG_ID}\", \"port\": \"${DATABRICKS_PORT}\" }" >> /root/.databricks-connect
```

Make sure to run all the commands in a line **using one `RUN` command.** Otherwise, the variable such as `DATABRICKS_HOST` or `DATABRICKS_API_TOKEN` may not properly propagate.

If you want to connect to a Databricks Cluster within a docker container you need more configuration. You can find the required details in this article: [How to Connect a Local or Remote Machine to a Databricks Cluster](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-connect-a-local-or-remote-machine-to-a-databricks-cluster-18e03afb53c6)

Answer (score 0):

The number of personal access tokens per user is limited to 600
But via bash is easy
echo "y
$(WORKSPACE-REGION-URL)
$(CSE-DEVELOP-PAT)
$(EXISTING-CLUSTER-ID)
$(WORKSPACE-ORG-ID)
15001" | databricks-connect configure

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access databricks models/download_artifacts using hostname and access token like how you do on databricks cli

`databricks configure --token --profile profile_name`

Databricks Host (should begin with https://): your_hostname

`Token : token`

if you have created profile name and pushed models and just want to access the model/artifacts in docker using this profile

**Add below code in the docker file.**

```
RUN pip install databricks_cli 

ARG HOST_URL

ARG TOKEN

RUN echo "[<profile name>]\nhost = ${HOST_URL}\ntoken = ${TOKEN}" >> ~/.databrickscfg
```

#this will created your .databrickscfg file with host and token after build the same way you do using databricks configure command

**Add args HOST_URL and TOKEN in the docker build**

e.g

your host name = https://adb-5443106279769864.19.azuredatabricks.net/

your access token = dapi********************53b1-2

```
sudo docker build -t test_tag --build-arg HOST_URL=<your host name> --build-arg TOKEN=<your access token> .
```

And now you can access your experiments using this profilename `Databricks:profile_name` in the code.